# How to format a number represented as a string?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I have a text file that has a price column like 000245 and like 001245.
I want to format the strings as 2.45 and 12.45?

Answer (score 2):

just convert it to int and divide by 100

```py
int(price)/100
```

Comment: btw There is no `casting` in python. Your example is of a conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the price to string.

```
>>> price = "000245"
>>> int(price)/100
2.45
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work with strings and want to get a string back:

```
s = '000245'

s = s.lstrip('0')

print (s[:-2]+'.'+s[-2:])
```

Output (as string):

```
2.45
```

Otherwise, still to preserve the variable type:

```
print (str(int(s)/100))
```